# Criteria to Follow a Caliphate/Emir of an Islamic Emirate/Government

Tags: sharia, islamic-government

I am non-Muslim history major student. I would like to know the criteria to determine a Caliphate. I would give an example of the very recent/last Caliphate in the Islamic world, i.e. the leader of the Islamic Emirate of Afghanistan (Taliban), *Mullah Mohammed Omar Mujahid or Mullah Omar*.

Mullah Omar called himself the Caliphate (Amir Al-Momenin) of all Muslims in the world. He ordered his followers to fully implement the Islamic Sharia laws, i.e. Quran and Hadith texts in almost 80% of Afghanistan from 1996 to 2001, longer than any other conservative Islamic group.

Even famous and recent Islamic figures like Usama Bin Laden and his followers decided to choose Mullah Omar as their Caliphate. **Based on Quran/Hadith, what are the criteria to follow a Caliphate of an Islamic Emirate/Government like Mullah Omar?**

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [ask], and take a [tour] in our [help]. All the time, there are people who come out and claim to be the leaders to follow, even during the time of the Prophet. Your question will draw opinion-best answers. Furthermore, to respond to your question, one has to know the details of the message of Mullah Mohammed Omar, which very few people, if any, will know.

Comment: @III-AK-III Thanks for the insight, I will edit the question and be more specific.

Comment: Also, just because someone declares himself or is declared a Caliph does not make him one, even if he has a sizable following. The Muslim world is not a clearly-defined entity, and the situation varies from what existed at the time of the Prophet or the imams mentioned above.

Comment: @SKarami Mullah Omar established an Islamic Emirate, implemented the Sharia laws, and majority of his society, represented by Ulemas, voted for him to be Caliphate. Omar did not declare himself to be Caliphate but was chosen. This is a historical fact. Now you say "someone declares himself or is declared a Caliph does not make him one". This is factually incorrect and your personal opinion. If you have an answer based on Quran/Hadith, I look forward to it.

Comment: @SarahMcLauren Thank you for correcting me. But the greater point I was trying to make is that the followers of Mullah Omar are/were a relatively small part of the Muslim world. The idea of a Caliphate is supposed to encompass the entire Muslim world, as it did in the early days of Islam. This is no longer possible; there are too many schisms, and attempts at unifying Muslims into one Ummah or nation have failed. However, the Hajj is still valid, even though Saudi leaders are demonstrably corrupt. But to form a Caliphate is NOT a requirement in Islam, & would only create more conflict.

Comment: @SKarami Thanks for the clarification. The starting point of all Caliphates, which seemed to be impossible at the beginning, happened in a small place with having conflicts and killing civilians. My question is not aimed whether it is moral or immoral to have a Caliphate or Emirate. All Caliphate and Emirs claimed that establishing an Islamic system, implementing Sharia laws and getting votes of Ulemas are enough to qualify as the Caliphate or Amir Al Momenin of all Muslims.

Comment: @SKarami Where do I find proofs for these claims in Quran/Hadith? If proofs don't exist in Islam, then all Caliphates from Abu-Bakr  to Mullah Omar just made up claims! And this means the concept of Islamic Caliphate/Government just does not exist in Islam.

Comment: The Caliphate is simply non-existent today, the person you cite in your answer is nothing more than a self proclaimed caliph.

Comment: @SarahMcLauren You’re jumping to conclusions. There is no “institution” of a Caliphate in the Quran. I’m not a hadeeth scholar, but I do know that after the Prophet Mohammad’s death (he being the leader of the Muslims), those who became, by vote, leaders of the Muslim community were called Khalifa, an Arabic word that means roughly “replacement” leader. They “replaced” the Prophet in leadership. Only the first four leaders are considered true Khalifas or the English word Cailiphs, and Shia Muslims dispute even that. Now some groups romanticize the Past and want to revive the “Caliphate.”

Comment: @SKarami the people which you said they aim to romanticize the past and want to revive the Caliphate have been involved in this business for 1400 years, and they reasoned based on Quran/Sunnah. There must have been something somewhere, any definitive or speculative verse or interpretation (Tafsir) in Quran (ignore Hadith for a while), on which these dudes from Hasan or Yazid let's say to Mullah Omar consolidated their power. I read a Khomeini's book about Guardianship of the Islamic Jurist where he debated for this which can be similar to Caliphate or Emirate, and he used some Quranic verses.

Comment: @SKarami My point is if Khomeini did find some verses, then the other dudes should have used some verses from Quran too.

Comment: @SarahMcLauren I suppose there are those who might try to extrapolate a desired meaning from a text whose meaning is NOT that, or some general Quranic statement used to justify an opinion. Adam was sent to earth as a “khalifa” – in this case, “steward” or responsible party. There is nothing specifically calling for there being only One Grand Ruler/ Cailiph by any name over all Muslims. There is, in passing, the description of Believers as people for whom “law/ governance is by mutual agreement between them.” That would be less authoritarian, more democratic. Clearly advocated in the Quran.

Comment: The question in the title is answerable, but you link it intricately with politics which makes it off-topic in my opinion as we are not here to validate or refute any such claims.